# Is Bitcoin a mesh network?

Tags: network

Considering following definition, can we say that bitcoin is a mesh network?

> > A mesh network uses a network topology in which each node (called a mesh node) relays data for the network. All nodes cooperate in the distribution of data in the network. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_networking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It broadcasts blocks and transactions using a logical mesh network, but that shouldn't be confused with [physical mesh network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_mesh_network) proposals.

Comment: What I mean is I think we can consider bitcoin network to have a mesh topology.

Comment: @Nur Okay... is that a question?

Comment: The question was above

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin is meant to be a redundant and cooperative network.  Everyone feeds everyone data.  So in a way, sure.